# How to prove that, given $p\geq 0$ there are $c<d$ such that $c(x^p+y^p)\leq (x+y)^p\leq d(x^p+y^p)$ for all $x,y\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Given $p\geq 0$ how can I show that there exists real numbers $c<d$ such that
$$c(x^p+y^p)\leq (x+y)^p\leq d(x^p+y^p)$$ for all $x,y \geq 0$

I was thinking to do something smiliar to the proof that two any norms on $\mathbb{R^n}$ are equivalents, but it was fruitless. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^p + y^p \le (x+y)^p + (x+y)^p = 2(x+ y)^p \implies \frac{1}{2}(x^p + y^p) \le (x+y)^p.
$$
$$
(x + y)^p \le (2 \max \{ x,y \})^p = 2^p (\max \{ x,y \})^p \le 2^p (x 
 + y)^p
$$

Comment: why the final inequality holds?

Comment: Because max is less than or equal to the sum (max is contained as a summand inside the sum): $\max \{ x, y\} \le x + y$.

Comment: Ohh yeah, this is obvious, sorry